# Finding Vcc from Zener diode?

Tags: circuit-design, diodes, schematics, zener

My apologies if this is a really simple question. I have very limited circuit knowledge.

I found this article (https://embedded-lab.com/blog/introducing-easy-pulse-a-diy-photoplethysmographic-sensor-for-measuring-heart-rate/) and I've been trying to re-construct it as a temporary prototype.

The (incomplete) circuit on the left has a Zener diode, and that confused me for a while. But after assuming that Vcc is greater than or equal to 2V, placing a voltmeter before and after the Zener diode it will measure 2V (given from Vz), so that explains Vref. However, the article never mentions the voltage of Vcc, is there a way I can find out through analysis? Or is the best method is to do some physical experimentation?

Also, is it correct that I can link a (blue) wire like so (connecting the Vref) in the following image? I'm confused at how the author of the article formatted the circuitry since it doesn't appear like a conventional schematic.

[image: modified circuit image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the points marked "Vref" should be connected together.

It is common practice to use "net labels" like this to show connections, particularly power and ground, to reduce wire clutter on the schematic.

At the end of the article you referenced they say "The board operates from 3-5.5V...", so Vcc can be anywhere within that range.